# Is it no longer needed to wrap connections in multiple threads with "with_connection"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, activerecord

I'm using the latest version of ActiveRecord and have a database with `domains` model, and have this, with a pool size of 10:

```
10.times.map do
  Thread.new do
    Domain.create(name: 'test')
  end
end.each(&:join)
```

Now, this code times out when I set a poll size of less than the number of threads, which indicates that ActiveRecord assigns a new connection poll to each thread (which is expected). But now I modified this code a bit:

```
10.times.map do
  Thread.new do
    Domain.create(name: 'test')
  end
end.each(&:join)

sleep 1
10.times.map do
  Thread.new do
    Domain.create(name: 'test')
  end
end.each(&:join)
```

I expected this code to fail, because after completing the 10 threads, I expected ActiveRecord to leave those 10 connections "orphaned" (nowehere I've used `with_connection`, which should have opened/closed them). Yet, this code completed successfully, indicating to me that somewhere along the line, ActiveRecord added a support to automatically close the poll, without using `with_connection`. Is this true?